# Spring Boot with Logback. Keep getting error and app is not starting

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I'm fighting with this problem for 3 days now. 
I have a Spring Boot 2.1.7 setup (very basic) with logback and lodash dependencies.

I'm trying to deploy my fat jar inside a docker image on Google Cloud Compute Engine.

I have the following logback-spring.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

  <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

    <springProfile name="default, local">
      <encoder>
        <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        <charset>utf8</charset>
      </encoder>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="test">
      <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
          <context/>
          <timestamp/>
          <version/>
          <logstashMarkers/>
          <mdc>
            <excludeMdcKeyName>X-B3-TraceId</excludeMdcKeyName>
            <excludeMdcKeyName>X-B3-SpanId</excludeMdcKeyName>
            <excludeMdcKeyName>X-B3-ParentSpanId</excludeMdcKeyName>
            <excludeMdcKeyName>X-Span-Export</excludeMdcKeyName>
          </mdc>
          <pattern>
            <pattern>
              {
              "app": "loyalty-api",
              "trace": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
              "span": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}",
              "spanParent": "%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-}"
              }
            </pattern>
          </pattern>
          <logLevel/>
          <loggerName/>
          <threadName/>
          <message/>
          <stackTrace/>
        </providers>
      </encoder>

    </springProfile>

  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>
        %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="asyncConsole" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="asyncConsole"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Nothing speciall...

Running the app with both local/test/default configuration but on my local machine I am able to fire the app - NO PROBLEM.

When running it inside the docker image at GCE i'm getting the following:

```
A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881485575Z ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@6:242 - no applicable action for [property], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][property]]

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881419449Z CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDCONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
```

full log:

```
A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.901892453Z Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894549994Z    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894546714Z    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894543454Z    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894540114Z    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894536754Z    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894533279Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894529837Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894526131Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894522116Z    at pl.code.house.makro.mapa.backend.MakroMapaApp.main(MakroMapaApp.java:12)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894502606Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894499251Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894495966Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894492606Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:341)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894489175Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894485713Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894482301Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894478740Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894475312Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894471886Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894468440Z    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:71)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894464831Z    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:114)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894461408Z    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:203)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894458006Z    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894454510Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894451107Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:341)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894447419Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894443310Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894439205Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894423936Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894420409Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894416783Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894395874Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:203)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894392446Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894389081Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:264)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894385687Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:289)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894382221Z    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894378816Z    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894375275Z    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:73)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894371460Z    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:220)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894366905Z    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:167)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894360945Z ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@6:242 - no applicable action for [property], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][property]]

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.894299813Z CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881678113Z    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881674309Z    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881671010Z    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881667402Z    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881664061Z    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881660595Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881656601Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881651627Z    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881648325Z    at pl.code.house.makro.mapa.backend.MakroMapaApp.main(MakroMapaApp.java:12)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881645065Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881641766Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881638210Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881620465Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:341)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881617075Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881613664Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881610244Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881606644Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881603255Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881599842Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881596423Z    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:71)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881592994Z    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:114)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881589547Z    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:203)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881586017Z    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881582696Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881579333Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:341)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881575811Z    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881571557Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881568147Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881564714Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881561210Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881557643Z    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881553805Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:203)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881538511Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881514747Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:264)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881511151Z    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:289)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881507526Z    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881503591Z    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881499700Z    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:73)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881495999Z    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:220)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881491479Z    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:167)

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881485575Z ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@6:242 - no applicable action for [property], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][property]]

A 2019-09-27T17:08:13.881419449Z CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDCONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN_IS_UNDEFINEDjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 

A 2019-09-27T17:08:11.735445525Z {"level":"INFO","logger_name":"org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector","message":"Kotlin reflection implementation not found at runtime, related features won't be available.","app":"makromapa-api","trace":"","span":"","spanParent":"","thread_name":"main","@timestamp":"2019-09-27T17:08:11.706Z","@version":"1"}

A 2019-09-27T17:08:11.588043416Z
```

Please guys can someone help me with this thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your app on your local machine inside a docker container?

Have you tried to replace `${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}` with a hardcoded pattern to check if it's really undefined (like the error suggests)?

You should also try to set the pattern explicitly in your Dockerfile.

Comment: No I did not test that, I thought that CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN is being set by Spring after the context is ran. 
Found out that when removing the sleuth dependency and adding the profile to the console appender it got running, but I still don't know how to run it with 'LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder' .